# Can't get html5 video in a webpage to loop or autoplay on android browser?

Tags: javascript, android, html, video

The final device I'll be putting this on is an android TV box, but I'm testing on my galaxy s5. Both are having the same issue.

I'm using Full Screen Browser by Klurige, and I originally had some GIF's at the bottom of the page that I wanted to loop, but they ended up being to clunky and big to run efficiently on the TVbox, so I decided to switch over to html5. I've tried with WEBM and MP4, both are doing the same thing.

I have the autoplay and loop attributes in the html5 video as such:
`<video id="zach" loop autoplay class="picture"><source src="P-Zach.webm">Error</video>`

Neither works be default in the browser. I just see a gray video icon. I can't even click to start it.

I've tried formatting in different ways and everything mentioned on the broken-links.com blog post people keep pointing to. I've tried javascript .play() options. None do anything.

If I add the controls attribute to the video, I can play the video, so I know the video file works, but it still won't loop.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it looks like it has something to do with android blocking webview from letting javascript control the html5 video.

That, in combination with the lack of native support for loop or autoplay attributes made me ditch fullscreen browser and switch to the only browser I could find that DID support those - Firefox.

I used an app called Ful!screen (or something like that) to remove the notification bar, loaded firefox with the webpage (with html5 playing and looping perfectly) and scrolled down slightly to hide the top bar.

Tada! Fullscreen browser with html5 video instead of GIFs.

Solved my own issue another way.